# Show that conjugate reciprocal works

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Prove that if $w$ is an $n$th root of unity, then $\frac{1}{\overline{w}}$ is also an $n$th root of unity.

$w^n = 1$ then $w = \cos(2k\pi/n) + \sin(2k\pi/n)$, but $|w| = 1$.

Let $w = x + iy$ then $\overline{w} = x - iy$ and $1/ \space \overline{w} =  \frac{w}{|w|^2} = w$.

Thus $(1/ \space \overline{w})^n = w^n = 1$.

Proof complete?

Comment: you are correct!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct!

You also could think:

$w^n=1 \Rightarrow |w|^n=1 \Rightarrow |w|=1 $

but

$|w|^2=w\overline{w}=1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{\overline{w}}=w \Rightarrow \left(\frac{1}{\overline{w}}\right)^n=w^n=1$